# When checkbox is clicked, how to know the state of the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

EDIT:
Please read the end part of the post, I know the part that tells which are unchecked needs to be inside the block of code, the issue here is that the first part of the code is not registering the "click". So can't do anything without that.

E2: May take the suggestion of adding a onclick to the boxes, since the code for boxes is generated with JS, I would add it once and all of them will get the function call, but that feels kinda ugly

I have a set of check boxes, and when one is clicked I need to return the values of the unchecked ones.
HTML:

```
<div id="myCheckboxList">
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="1" checked>1
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="2" checked>2
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="3" checked>3
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $("input[name=myList]").on("click",function(){
    console.log("triggered");
    //code here to find which ones are unchecked

  });
});
```

I have tried to also add this in the code

```
$boxes = $('input[name=myList]:not(:checked)');
$boxes.each(function(){
    // Do stuff with for each unchecked box
});
```

Unfortunatly the "triggered" in not getting output to console, so unsure why it is so, and how would i get an event to happen when the checkboxes are hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code directly to a fiddle, and it works fine. You could be missing the jquery library?

EDIT:

Just to be sure, I updated the snippet to generate the inputs, and it still works fine.

```js
$(function() {
  var html = '<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="1" checked>1'
  +'<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="2" checked>2'
  +'<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="3" checked>3';
  
  $("#myCheckboxList").html(html);

  $("input[name=myList]").on("click", function() {
    console.log("triggered");
    //code here to find which ones are unchecked
    $boxes = $('input[name=myList]:not(:checked)');
    $boxes.each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCheckboxList">
</div>
```

Comment: This is so strange that it works here and its not working on mine, could there be an issue that the input fields are generated and then inserted into the <div>??

Comment: Shouldn't be. Once they exist, the `$('input[name=myList]:not(:checked)')` should grab them (assuming they have `name=myList`).

Comment: For me it is not even registering the click, which is the biggest concern

Comment: Without more info, my guess is that your selector doesn't match your DOM. So make sure you don't have any typos and the name of your inputs match what's in your selector.

Comment: As for jQuery lib in cosnole  jQuery.fn.jquery returns  "3.2.1" ,  so that would be a no, and i have no idea why the click event not firing.

Comment: Maybe also try moving the click function outside the document ready function (`$(function() {...`).

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried generating the inputs via jQuery and inserting into to the <div>, but that works as well.

Comment: Yeah this is really strange behaviour, i added a onclick to input and just wrote into a separate function and that works fine, im not sure if this is nested in multiple <div> and i cant find the input fields, Im 100% spelling is correct so it leaves me thinking the selector needs extra work for it to function like intended

Comment: Yes, that would be my conclusion as well. Something's not right with the selector. I suggest using the developer tools in your browser to figure out exactly where your inputs are positioned in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i mean its there is 3 divs above the div that contains my input fields, i'm a bit new to this only few months learning so i wasn't aware that the selector didn't scan whole page and look for any input with name="myName"

Comment: Well, it does. The selectors grab everything unless narrowed down. So, simply `$(input)` will look at all the inputs in the page while `$(#myId input)` would only look at the inputs **inside** the `#myId` element.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to:

```
let v = $(this).attr('value');
if(v === 1){ // box 1 selected
```

Adding this inside your `'click'` handler should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, nor sure if I understand what you mean. Do i replace the ("click", function(){}) for ("click", function($(this).attr('value')){})

Comment: When you use '$' in jquery to select an HTMLEntity, the 'this' value refers to the context of that entity. Since you are using $ to select input type, you will get multiple options. I would also suggest using jquery's each method to add the click callback. The 'attr' method is used for selecting a property inside the element and, checking for the value assigned to each can help to know which box was it is you are processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
$(function(){
   
  $("input[name=myList]").on("click",function(){
    var uncheck=[];
    //console.log("triggered");
    //code here to find which ones are unchecked

  
  $boxes = $("input[name=myList]:not(:checked)");
  $boxes.each(function(){
    // Do stuff with for each unchecked box
    uncheck.push($(this).attr('value'))
    console.log(uncheck);
  });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCheckboxList">
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="1" checked>1
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="2" checked>2
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="3" checked>3
</div>
```

Comment: this is what you are looking?

Comment: this don't even return the value to console, it will only return values on first load of the page, and any changes will just log "triggered"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your each script inside your click event.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name=myList]").on("click",function(){
    $("input[name=myList]:not(:checked)").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="myCheckboxList">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="1" checked>1
  <input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="2" checked>2
  <input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="3" checked>3
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My answer is lonely. ⊙﹏⊙

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add an "onclick" method in your html. This will call a javascript function whenever the checkbox is clicked. That function can contain any logic for your checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myList" value="1" checked onclick="checkboxChangeEvent();">1
```

Then you can implement your javascript function to return a list of unchecked boxes or find the input boxes  by name and return the alert as in previous answers.

```
function checkboxChangeEvent(){
    $boxes = $('input[name=myList]:not(:checked)');
    $boxes.each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: May just have to go with this if i cant figure out why the click event is not firing